# Excel - Text transformation keeping Roman Numerals uppercase

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a CSV file that is exported from another program with one of the columns being the title. The data in the original program is all uppercase for the title field so when it exports, the title looks something like this: 'COLUMN TITLE IV'. If I try to transform the text to just be uppercase, the title ends up looking like so: "Column Title Iv".

Is there any way of keeping the Roman Numerals in the title as uppercase but transform the rest of it to proper capitalization?

My file has about 5,000 entry's so I need a way to do this in a non manual way.

**EDIT:** What happens if I have a title like 'CPR FUNDAMENTALS IV'? Is there a way to keep CPR caps and to just alter 'FUNDAMENTALS' to 'Fundamentals'?

Comment: Surely there can't be many of the entries which are column headers. Won't it just be the entries in the first row that need attention? You could use a regular expression to find the Roman numerals (`\b[lxvi]+\b` will find all numbers up to 99), but you haven't said whether you are editing the CSV file or changing the Excel data after importing, and the precise syntax will depend on the editor you use.

Comment: I am editing the CSV file in excel after the export from the original program.

Comment: Very simple with *VBA* .............. is this approach okay?

Comment: I've never used that before but if it's very simple with it, that'd be great. I'm sure I'd be able to figure it out.

Comment: And how many column headers are there? You can easily spend more time getting a regular expression right than it would take to do it manually.

Comment: There are 4 columns in the exported CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install the following User Defined Functions in a standard module:

```
Public Function Properize(s As String) As String
    Dim temp As String, i As Long, L As Long, U As Long
    ary = Split(UCase(s), " ")
    U = UBound(ary)
    L = LBound(ary)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = L To U
            If IsRoman(ary(i)) Then
            Else
                ary(i) = .Proper(ary(i))
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Properize = Join(ary, " ")
End Function


Public Function IsRoman(s As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, L As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If InStr(1, "IVXLCDM", Mid(s, i, 1)) = 0 Then
            IsRoman = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsRoman = True
End Function
```

Then with text in cell **A1**, **B1** enter:

```
=Properize(A1)
```

[image]

The functions will "upper case" Roman Numerals and words that "look like" Roman Numerals *( for example CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC)*

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: @ACanadianCoder if you need help with the VBA, just update the post

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks!